# Error Whilst running Solidity with Python(py-solc)

Tags: python-3.x, solidity

I have been running my code which involves deployment of smart contract to Ethereum Ropsten network. I ran this successfully for some time but last week did installed another software after which I started getting these errors:
`command: solc --combined-json abi,asm,ast,bin,bin-runtime,clone-bin,devdoc,interface,opcodes,userdoc
return code: 1
stderr:
stdout:
Invalid option to --combined-json: clone-bin`

I have no clue why I'm getting them. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have solution now. Solidity has a newer version of solidity which is v0.5.1 which is not compatible with `py-solc` so what should be done to following the instructions [here](https://github.com/ethereum/py-solc#installing-the-solc-binary) install `version 0.4.25` and set `SOLC_BINARY` env pointing to your binaries.